# Можно ли употреблять слово "совместно" по отношению к слитному написанию слов?

Tags: наречия

В последнее время часто слышу слово "совместно", когда у меня человек спрашивает о форматировании документов, слитно ли какое-нибудь слово пишется.

Comment: "Совместно" — это о действии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Жуткая дичь! Не только не "совместно", но даже и не "вместе", как говорили порой в начальной школе.

Исключительно СЛИТНО или РАЗДЕЛЬНО, так и словарь называется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]